# Enable sshfs for non-admin users on CentOS 6.8

Tags: linux, mount, centos-6, sshfs

Would it be possible to enable sshfs to mount for users without admin permissions in CentOS 6.8?

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the sudoers file at /etc/sudoers using visudo

Add a line like this:

`theusername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /full/path/to/command`

So for a user lets say mary

`mary ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/sshfs`

Or if you want to restrict to just the command run a certain way (Arguments):

`mary ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/sshfs -o allow_other,defer_permissions root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/ /mnt/droplet`